# How to map Home Controller from Different Project/Module - .NET Framework 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I've an existing application using ASP .NET MVC (VB & .NET Framework 4.5).Below is the code for HomeController.vb.

```
    Imports System.Web.Mvc
    Namespace Controllers
    Public Class HomeController       
    <AllowAnonymous>
    Function Login() As ActionResult
        If Not User Is Nothing AndAlso User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = True Then
            Return Redirect("/mvc/action/main")
        Else
            Return Redirect("/mvc")
        End If
    End Function      
    End Class
    End Namespace
```

I've converted HomeController.vb to HomeController.cs and kept the .cs controller file in different project/module.

Code for HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Admin
{
public class HomeController 
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        if (!User == null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
            return Redirect("/mvc/action/main");
        else
            return Redirect("/mvc");
    }
   
    }
    }
```

The Question here is how I can access the new HomeController.cs file in RouteConfig.vb

Sample code for RouteConfig.vb

```
  routes.MapRoute(
         name:="login",
         url:="login",
        defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Login"}
    )
```

Please assist to map the new controller to the old RouteConfig.

Comment: Is the different project is added as reference in the vb project?

Comment: yes, I've added as reference to the vb project